# Excel UserForm with list to select multiple items

Tags: excel, vba

This seems like a very simple problem but I just cannot find documentation for it, on MSDN.

How can I create a UserForm in Excel that will let **user** select many items?

Example(assuming that this will be done using listbox, otherwise better solution will be used):

```
_______
|item1 | <- pick this
|item2 |
|item3 | <- ,and pick this
|item4 |
|______|
```

Comment: Where and how are these items listed in UserForm? Have you used listbox or any other controls? If you use list box control, you can select multiple items.

Comment: Good question I haven't figured it out but list box sounds like most reasonalbe solution, becasue amount of items on my list varies.

Comment: Check out the below link, it will help you: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/multiple-list-box-selections.html

Comment: Or [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161598) from Microsoft.  Method 2 is what I think your looking for.

Comment: Don't forget to set the MultiSelect property of your Listbox to either 1 or 2.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions they all look promising, I'll look into them, and I'll be back with results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`me.listbox.multiselect=1` lets user select multiple lines.

further you need to loop through your list `for i=0 to me.listbox.listcount-1` ,

and to check if item is selected `if me.listbox.selected(i) = true then`.... do stuff

note : a list starts with 0 (like in my FOR loop), so your first item is called `me.listbox.list (0).value`.

info on the selected method : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251644%28v=office.15%29.aspx